# setting resolution xrandr --addmode

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, screen-resolution, xrandr

I am unable to set screen resolution with xrandr from within virtualbox. This is a VM running ubuntu 12.04 and the driver supports this resolution as VM from the same iso runs it on the same machine. Why does  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) occur?

step 0

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32000 x 32000
VBOX0 connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

step 1

```
cvt 1920 1080
1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

step 2

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

step 3

```
~$ xrandr --addmode VBOX0  1920x1080_60.00
   X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
   Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
   Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
   Serial number of failed request:  20
   Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

Comment: This might be considered [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Comment: What gave your /var/log/Xorg.0.log??

Answer (score 0):

If you have done this process before, something happens when you try to use the same name. name the mode something else and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is semicolon

try now

```
xrandr --addmode VBOX0  "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. From Linux Shell run cvt to get scanlines frequencies from desired resolution

> `cvt 1440 900`
> or
> cvt 1440 900 FrequencyValue (Optional in Hz) -> cvt 1440 900 75

Output:

```
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

2. Then run xrandr to list all display output ports and resolutions available

> ```
> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
> VGA-1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
>    1024x768      60.00  
>    800x600       60.32    56.25  
>    848x480       60.00  
>    640x480       59.94  
> HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> ```

3. Next we must add new resolution copying output result from cvt command (text after string 'Modeline')

> ```
> xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
> xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1440x900_60.00"
> ```